# Debugging in expo : physical device

Tags: react-native, debugging, expo, reactotron

I would like to debug my networks request in Expo. 
I'm using Reactotron : it works on my ios emulator but I got nothing on my physical device : 
I'm using expo on an android and a tunnel expo connection.

Here is my config in my `App.js` :

```js
import Reactotron from 'reactotron-react-native'

Reactotron
  .setAsyncStorageHandler(AsyncStorage) // AsyncStorage would either come from `react-native` or `@react-native-community/async-storage` depending on where you get it from
  .configure() // controls connection & communication settings
  .useReactNative() // add all built-in react native plugins
  .connect() // let's connect!

export default function App(props) {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    Reactotron.connect()
  });
...
```

What do I need to change to debug request on my physical device ?